# R shiny - nothing showing on the main panel after selecting the directory where the file was stored

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to dynamically select directory from the computer where files are stored. Currently there is a sas dataset named 'sample' stored under my win10 PC desktop.

I would like to print out the first 10 observations of the sample dataset I read into, but it is not working without showing any error.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(haven)
library(DT) 

ui<-fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    shinyDirButton("dir", "Chose directory", "Upload")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("sasdat")
  )
  
))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  dir <- reactive(input$dir)
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'dir', roots=c(name=getwd()), session=session)
  path1 <- reactive({
    return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$dir)))
  })
  
  data1 <- eventReactive(input$path1, {
    sample <- data.frame(read_sas(paste0(path1, "sample.sas7bdat")))
    sample
  })
  output$sasdat = DT::renderDataTable({
    head(data1(),10)
  })
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(haven)
library(DT) 

ui<-fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    shinyDirButton("dir", "Chose directory", "Upload")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("sasdat")
  )
  
))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  #dir <- reactive(input$dir)
  volumes <- getVolumes()
  shinyDirChoose(input=input, 'dir', roots=volumes, session=session)
  path1 <- reactive({
    parseDirPath(volumes, input$dir)
  })
  
  data1 <- eventReactive(path1(), {
    sample <- data.frame(haven::read_sas(paste0(path1(), "sample.sas7bdat")))
    sample
  })
  output$sasdat = renderDT({
    head(data1(),10)
  })
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Or you can use `fileInput` to choose a file from your pc...

```
ui<-fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("sasdata1", "Choose a SAS dataset", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".sas7bdat"),
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("sasdat")
  )
  
))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  data1 <- reactive({
    req(input$sasdata1)
    inData1 <- input$sasdata1
    if (is.null(inData1)){ return(NULL) }
    mydata1 <- haven::read_sas(inData1$datapath)
  })

  output$sasdat = renderDT({
    head(data1(),10)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```